# PHP/Laravel path error when moving project to test server

Tags: php, laravel

I have been developing my project on my local machine (Windows) for a while now and now that I have tried pushing it to my test server (Linux) I'm getting errors about files still referencing my local machine's path. I'm trying to figure out how I can clear it or set it to the new, correct, path.

All artisan commands throw the error immediately whilst `composer du/install/update` work until `Generating optimized autoload files`. In addition to `composer du` I've tried `php artisan cache:clear`. It all throws the same error.

Here is the error it's throwing as well as the file the error is coming from:

https://pastebin.com/0dS18UQs

Thanks in advance, it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have two issues that I see: `Cannot create cache directory /home/202967.cloudwaysapps.com/qjbpthzgsh/.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. `. Make sure that you're in the correct directory, and that you have write access to both `/home/202967.cloudwaysapps.com/qjbpthzgsh/` and `/home/202967.cloudwaysapps.com/qjbpthzgsh/.composer`, as well as all of the subdirectories beneath it. `require(C:\apps\landlord\routes/breadcrumbs.php)` That's looking for a Windows directory instead of a linux directory. Try using a dynamic link instead of a hard-coded link to the file.

Comment: your cache folder is not writable by composer

Comment: @YAMM Would this cause an issue? I've deployed projects before with this error which still worked fine.

Comment: @aynber Thanks a lot. I suspect that the windows path not being updated is the heart of the issue but I can't seem to find where I can update the path that is being called in the error (`require(C:\apps\landlord\routes/breadcrumbs.php)`).

Comment: Try `grep -R breadcrumbs.php *` from the root directory, on the linux server. It should help narrow it down. You can also try `grep -R 'C:\apps' *` to see if that path is hardcoded somewhere

Comment: Make sure your storage folder has writable permissions and run composer update under your project directory.

Comment: @RASELRANA I have the `storage` folder set to 755 permissions. Is that correct?

Comment: @aynber Thanks. The second command yields no results whilst the first one returns very many. Surely that means that there is nowhere where the path is hard-coded? I definitely never entered any path in for that plugin.

Comment: Can you show your composer.json, specifically the scripts section?

Comment: @aynber please see https://pastebin.com/34jkxhFU

Thanks again for all the help, I really am lost and appreciate it!

Comment: Try removing `"@php artisan package:discover --ansi"` for now, also also make sure there's nothing referenced in your `.env` file.

Comment: @aynber thanks a lot. I checked the `.env` and there is no reference anywhere to my file structure. I removed the line you mentioned and now that error has gone but I am still getting the original file path error. What are the implications of removing the line you mentioned? Is it not perhaps that the line we removed is only giving issues because of the original error which PHP is throwing? Here is the latest error output when trying to migrate. I did flush composer's cache. https://pastebin.com/paGN3cW2

Comment: Removing that line just stops it from using artisan commands while you're getting the issue worked out. I'd suggest putting it back afterwards. Try `rm composer.lock; composer clearcache; composer install; composer dumpautoload` and see if they all work.

Answer (score 1):

I appear to have found the issue. The directories were hard-coded (by Laravel, I assume) in the `bootstrap/cache/config.php` file.

Thanks to everyone for all the help.

Comment: Nice job Charl, can you check your answer as 'the' answer please?

Answer (score -1):

Try this command : 
sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.composer

or try this

sudo chown -R {user} /home/{user}/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org

Comment: Please explain **why** one should use these commands. Keep in mind that others should be able to learn from your answer

Comment: @NicoHaase this command will give user permission (change ownership) so that  current user should have every control on the directory.

Comment: Please add all such explanation to the answer, not to the comment section. Additionally, explain how this is related to the question - have a look at the answer that Charl gave to his own question